# Fetch 1 row as a link (<a href>)

Tags: url, hyperlink, html-table, row, fetchall

I'm fetching some rows from my database into a HTML table like this:

```
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT sportnaam, beschrijving, link FROM sporten");
$stmt->execute();
$arrValues = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// open the table
print "<table >\n";
print "<tr>\n";

// add the table headers
foreach ($arrValues[0] as $key => $useless){
    print "<th></th>";
}
print "</tr>";
// display data
foreach ($link as $rows){
    print "<tr>";
}
foreach ($arrValues as $row){
    print "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $key => $val){
    print "<p>$val</p>";
    }
    print "</tr>\n";
}
// close the table
print "</table>\n";
}
```

The problem is that I'd like to print the `link` (which I selected above) as a actual link. (so like `a href` ...) But I've no idea how to do this and looked everywhere for a solution.

Comment: link is an actual row in your database? what data do you store in that specific row? You could make it clickable something like: `<?php foreach ($arrValues as $row){ echo '<a href=". $row['link'] .">The Link</a>'; }; ?>`

Comment: Yes it is. The data is a youtube link, but the problem is that Sportname and description shouldn't be clickable.

Comment: Could you give the output which is given from the link row?

Comment: It's outputting normal links but not clickable.

Comment: just a http://ksjflkds.com link?

Comment: Yes, but it's not clickable!

Comment: Yes I understand. You're trying to use $link as $row, but what is $link? You did not define that somewhere.

Comment: Oh i just saw I pasted the code wrong oops!.I'll keept trying but thanks anyway!